# Autolayout: Adding a view break my otherwise working resizing - ideas?

Tags: ios, autolayout

In my app, I have the following setup:

TextView (self.textView)

Toolbar

When the keyboard become visible, I add a constraint that pushes the bottom of the text view up with the required number of pixels.

```
spacer =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                   constraintWithItem:self.textView
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                   toItem:self.view
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                   multiplier:1.0
                                   constant:-height];
[self.view addConstraint:spacer];
```

When the keyboard disappears, I remove the constraint.

THIS WORKS FINE. However...

I want to add an imageview that lies on top of the text view. This seems straightforward. But now the "dismiss keyboard" resize is broken.

Here's the code I use to create the imageview, and pin it to the textview bounds.

```
self.overlay = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

[self.overlay setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.view addSubview:self.overlay];

[self.view addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint
                           constraintWithItem:self.overlay
                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                           toItem:self.textView
                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                           multiplier:1.0
                           constant:0]];
[self.view addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint
                           constraintWithItem:self.overlay
                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                           toItem:self.textView
                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                           multiplier:1.0
                           constant:0]];
[self.view addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint
                           constraintWithItem:self.overlay
                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                           toItem:self.textView
                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                           multiplier:1.0
                           constant:0]];
[self.view addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint
                           constraintWithItem:self.overlay
                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                           toItem:self.textView
                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                           multiplier:1.0
                           constant:0]];
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

Here's how it should look:

Initial before keyboard showing

[image: Initial before keyboard showing]

Keyboard showing

[image: Keyboard showing]

Keyboard removed. Layout should be back to initial state, but instead I get this

[image: Should be back to initial state, but instead I get this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Set the content hugging priority for the tool bar to 1.000 to avoid that it gets all stretched out.